# Eclipse: Open file path from source code

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse you can easily navigate to a Java class by moving the mouse pointer onto a class name while pressing and holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or move cursor onto the class name and press <kbd>F3</kbd>).

Is it possible to open resource files like that? Example: In the current (Java) editor I have this Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Implementation of /src/main/resources/rfc/rfc2324.rfc
 */
```

There's a matching file `/src/main/resources/rfc/rfc2324.rfc`. I need to open file names from source code quite often. Is there some feature, some hotkey or a plugin that supports this?

Answer (score 0):

yah, you can use  to open any resource in your project `ctrl+shift+R`, then you just enter the resource name you want to open, or you can select the resource name that you want to open and enter `ctrl+shift+R`.

Comment: Yea, I know, i can copy the file name and then `Open Resource`. But that's way too complicated (especially because the file names contain `.` and `-`). I'd rather like to press a key or click mouse while a key is pressed.